Using HTTP Cient In SSIS Script Task - Need Assistance
I am attempting to use HTTP client from a SSIS Script task in VS 2019 and when I debug it the code will just spin and if it but a break point afterwards the VS will freeze.
The following is my code:
 public class TokenInfo
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; } = "";
        public string token_type { get; set; } = "";
        public int expires_in { get; set; } = 0;
        public string refresh_token { get; set; } = "";
    }

    private TokenInfo tmpToken;

    public void Main()
    {
        ObtainToken();
        
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    public async void ObtainToken()
    {
        string connectionString = "";
        string sql = null;
        string test;


        //test = MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["USER::BookingRefResult"].Value.ToSt

        test = Dts.Variables["User::strOne"].Value.ToString();

        Dts.Variables["User::json"].Value = "muck muck";

        // var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string serviceUrl = "https://deltekvp-dev.perkinswill.com/vantagepoint/api/token";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {{oauth_token}}");

        var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", "ADMIN_API"));

        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "VP123!"));
        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Integrated", "N"));
        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Client_Id", "5586af3c19de4958858a8148427c76ad"));
        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "1da607c920744de1bceb1cbdf38aede7"));
        collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("culture", "en-US"));

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
        request.Content = content;

        var response =  await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //  tmpToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenInfo>(json);

            Dts.Variables["User::json"].Value = json;

            return;
        }
    }

Has anyone been successful with this?  My main issue is the following var response =  await client.SendAsync(request);
Should I not be using HTTPClient in SSIS? I am using 2019 and tried to upgrade to .Net 5.0 but VS would not take it.  Because with 5.0 you can use HTTPClient.Send.
Tried a lot of things and nothing has worked.

Please add your code to the question as code, and not as an image

Added the code the standard way. Thanks!
